# My charger has stopped working. I have AppleCare. How do I go about getting a new charger?

Tags: macbook-pro, applecare, charger

My MacBook Pro mid-2015 charger mysteriously* stopped working today. I have AppleCare but I live in Ireland and there are no Apple Stores here.

Can I go into an Apple authorised reseller and get a new charger for free because I have AppleCare?

If not, what's the process?

*I thought I saw a spark in my room 2 days ago. I was falling asleep at the time. I got up, checked the plugs and unplugged everything in the room (including my MacBook). I can't remember if I've charged the laptop since then though.

Comment: https://locate.apple.com/ie/en/

Comment: And what then? Can I go into an Apple authorised reseller and get a new charger for free because I have AppleCare?

Comment: Does another charger work on the MacBook Pro? Likewise, does the bad charger work on another MacBook Pro? Just a little troubleshooting to determine whether it is the charger or the MacBook that is having the problem. Depending on your circumstances, you may not be able to do these troubleshooting tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppleCare does include replacing broken chargers. I went to an official apple reseller and they replaced the charger without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can always initiate service from https://locate.apple.com and choose your provider of choice. The online self service is much, much better now, so starting with Apple support is often the fastest way for you to get things through the hoops and to a technician to do the exchange for you if a mail in exchange isn't offered.

In your case, you can direct the service to Ireland at https://locate.apple.com/ie/en/ and just click the box that says service.

[image]

Not all resellers also provide service, so doing a little digging usually saves you a trip and some time.

Comment: That just shows me where the authorised Apple reseller shops are. I've emailed the shop to ask.

Comment: @GreenRails If you didn't know to select service, that link might not help. I've edited my post to address Ireland (or you can use the flag control in the top right) as well as to indicate that you need "service" as opposed to training, consulting or sales.